# How do I read this kanji from an old book?

Tags: meaning, words, kanji, readings

It is from a book titled ガンビアの春, or Spring in Gambier, that I am translating for my senior capstone project. I can read 活, but I couldn't tell you what the second character is. This author tends to use outdated kanji, such as 附くrather than 付く, and so on. I can't find it by writing it or inputting the radicals.

[image]

This word seems to be an adjective. The surrounding sentence is as follows:

> …「キャンパス・アウルズ」（キャンパスのふくろう）という楽団を組織して、一九二九年の夏にはヨーロッパへ演奏旅行に出かけたというから、なかなか活＿な学生であったらしい。

Comment: That is 潑, which seems to be an older version of 溌. So the word in question can also be written as 活溌.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's it!

Comment: ガンビア is not the Gambia?

Comment: Not in this context! It's a book about Kenyon College, which is in Gambier, Ohio

Comment: Ah, that's interesting! I actually know someone who went there. I just checked the author's Wiki page: 「1959年（昭和34年）には、ケニオン大学へ1年間の留学のため、夫婦でアメリカ合衆国オハイオ州ガンビア村に滞在した経験を『ガンビア滞在記』として著した」 Learned something new today!

Comment: Google’s handwriting input method recognizes those old forms if the input language is set to “Detect language” (or Traditional Chinese).

Comment: Old form of 発 is 發, as other guys metioned.

"發" This kind of old forms are called 旧字体 (kyujitai) or 異体字 (itaiji).

New forms are 新字体 (shinjitai).

This link is useful to know some of them.
https://www.benricho.org/moji_conv/14_shin_kyu_kanji.html

Comment: Thank you so much for the words and that article!!! I've been really stumped trying to look up "old forms" and having the word for it will really help. Thanks to aguijonazo for the tip on writing them too:)

Comment: It was not meant to be a tip on writing those characters. Once you have them recognized on a system, you can look them up by copying and pasting them.

Comment: Yeah I get that, I meant handwriting input. Sorry for the confusion.